# Set meta information for Django app

Tags: django, django-apps

I have a few apps installed on my Django project.  I would like for some of the apps to be able to get information from some of the other apps.  Therefore, I am looking to give each of the apps some basic meta information about permissions.

So, if I have three apps: A1, A2, and A3.

I would like to set A1 to be read only.  Set A2 to be read/write.  Set A3 to not be able to read or write from.

The meta descriptions are mostly for my own sanity.  These apps won't be working with apps that I didn't write.

Is there a way to add such meta data at the app level?  Perhaps through an unused description field for the Django app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why you would ever need this, but normally you place all meta information in `__init__.py` of the app. Then you can access it from another app:

`myapp1/__init__.py`:

```
version = '0.1.0'
permissions = ['read', 'write']
```

`myapp2/utils.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
import importlib

for app_name in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    app = importlib.import_module(app_name)
    if hasattr(app, 'permissions') and 'write' in app.permissions:
        do_something()
```

Comment: also might want to edit it so that it is `__init__`.py... to escape the bold